# Google SSO ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: .net, google-authentication

I’ve a legacy asp.net web forms application and a requirement to protect an administrative section using Google Single Sign On.  At this point there is no scope to update the site to something more modern.  From what I can tell, there are 2 options:

[Google SSO Server Flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) - after exchanging the code for an an access token, do I still need to handle refresh tokens?  Is there a way to determine if the token has expired or do I need to use IssuedUtc and ExpiresInSeconds before attempting to verify the token.  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1486 has sample c# code.

[Google OWIN](http://codegeeken.blogspot.com/2017/06/aspnet-web-forms-implementing-google.html) - I do not need to support local accounts, just Google.

Are there any alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a detailed step by step [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-oauth2-0-authorization-for-google-in-asp-net/)

It shows how to setup a google account as well as how to integrate it in webforms
Let us know if you have more questions

Comment: I haven’t been able to test, however this looks like a complete example! Thanks